# Token ring protocol java

Tags: java, tcp, token

I am trying to get this source code working in order to learn about network programming. It was sending packets through the three classes initially but isnt any longer even with the same code. The problem occurs when in the Tokenclient1 class after no is entered and the packet isnt being sent to the second client.

Any ideas why is is no longer working?

```
    import java.net.*; 

    public class TokenServer {     
        public static void main(String agrs[])throws Exception         {                         

            while(true)             {             
                Server sr=new Server();             
                sr.recPort(8000);             
                sr.recData();             
                }         
            } 
        } 
    class Server {         
        boolean hasToken=false;     
        boolean sendData=false;     
        int recport;         

        void recPort(int recport)     {         
            this.recport=recport;     
            }     

        void recData()throws Exception     {         
            byte buff[]=new byte[256];         
            DatagramSocket ds;         
            DatagramPacket dp;         
            String str;                 
            ds=new DatagramSocket(recport);         
            dp=new DatagramPacket(buff,buff.length);         
            ds.receive(dp);         
            ds.close();                 
            str=new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());         
            System.out.println("The message is "+str);     
            } 
    }







    import java.io.*; 
    import java.net.*; 
    public class TokenClient1 {     
        public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception         {             
            InetAddress lclhost;             
            BufferedReader br;             
            String str="";             
            TokenClient12 tkcl,tkser;             
            //boolean hasToken;             
            //boolean setSendData;                         

            while(true)             {             
                lclhost=InetAddress.getLocalHost();             
                tkcl = new TokenClient12(lclhost);             
                tkser = new TokenClient12(lclhost);                    
                //tkcl.setSendPort(9001);             
                tkcl.setSendPort(9004);             
                tkcl.setRecPort(8002);             
                lclhost=InetAddress.getLocalHost();             
                tkser.setSendPort(9000);             

                if(tkcl.hasToken == true)             {                 
                    System.out.println("Do you want to enter the Data --> YES/NO");                 
                    br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                 
                    str=br.readLine();                 
                    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))                 {                       
                        System.out.println("ready to send");                     
                        tkser.setSendData = true;                     
                        tkser.sendData();                     
                        tkser.setSendData = false;                 
                        }                 
                    else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))                 {                     
                        System.out.println("i m in else");                     
                        //tkcl.hasToken=false;                     
                        tkcl.sendData();                     
                        tkcl.recData();                 
                        System.out.println("i m leaving else");                 
                        }             
                    }             
                else             {             
                    System.out.println("ENTERING RECEIVING MODE...");                 
                    tkcl.recData();             
                    }     
                } 
            } 
        }                    
    class TokenClient12 {     
        InetAddress lclhost;     
        int sendport,recport;     
        boolean hasToken = true;     
        boolean setSendData = false;     
        TokenClient12 tkcl,tkser;     
        TokenClient12(InetAddress lclhost)     {                 
            this.lclhost = lclhost;     
            }         
        void setSendPort(int sendport)     {         
            this.sendport = sendport;     
            }     void setRecPort(int recport)        {         
                this.recport = recport;     
                }     
            void sendData() throws Exception         {         
                BufferedReader br;         
                String str="Token";         
                DatagramSocket ds;         
                DatagramPacket dp;                     

                if(setSendData == true)         {             
                    System.out.println("sending ");             
                    System.out.println("Enter the Data");             
                    br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));             
                    str = "ClientOne....." + br.readLine();             
                    System.out.println("now sending");                             
                    }             
                ds = new DatagramSocket(sendport);             
                dp = new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(),str.length(),lclhost,sendport-1000);             
                ds.send(dp);             
                ds.close();             
                setSendData = false;             
                hasToken = false;     
                }         

            void recData()throws Exception     {         
                String msgstr;         
                byte buffer[] = new byte[256];         
                DatagramSocket ds;         
                DatagramPacket dp;         
                ds = new DatagramSocket(recport);         
                dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);         
                ds.receive(dp);         
                ds.close();         
                msgstr = new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());         
                System.out.println("The data is "+msgstr);                 

                if(msgstr.equals("Token"))             {                 
                    hasToken = true;             
                    }     
                }     
    }








        import java.io.*; 
        import java.net.*; 



        public class TokenClient2 {     
            static boolean setSendData ;     
            static boolean hasToken ;     

            public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception         {             

                InetAddress lclhost;             
                BufferedReader br;             
                String str1;             
                TokenClient21 tkcl;             
                TokenClient21 ser;             

                while(true)             {             
                    lclhost=InetAddress.getLocalHost();             
                    tkcl = new TokenClient21(lclhost);             
                    tkcl.setRecPort(8004);                    
                    tkcl.setSendPort(9002);             
                    lclhost=InetAddress.getLocalHost();             
                    ser = new TokenClient21(lclhost);             
                    ser.setSendPort(9000);             
                    System.out.println("entering if");                

                    if(hasToken == true)             {                 
                        System.out.println("Do you want to enter the Data --> YES/NO");                 
                        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                 
                        str1=br.readLine();                 
                        if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))                 {                        
                            System.out.println("ignorecase");                     
                            ser.setSendData = true;                     
                            ser.sendData();                     }                 
                        else if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))                 {                     
                            tkcl.sendData();                     
                            hasToken=false;                 
                            }             
                        }             
                    else             {             
                        System.out.println("entering recieving mode");                    
                        tkcl.recData();                 
                        hasToken=true;            
                        }         
                    }     
                } 
            } 
        class TokenClient21 {     
            InetAddress lclhost;     
            int sendport,recport;     
            boolean setSendData = false;     
            boolean hasToken = false;     
            TokenClient21 tkcl;     
            TokenClient21 ser;         
            TokenClient21(InetAddress lclhost)     {                 
                this.lclhost = lclhost;     }        
            void setSendPort(int sendport)     {         
                this.sendport = sendport;     
                }     
            void setRecPort(int recport)        {         
                this.recport = recport;     
                }     
            void sendData() throws Exception     {         
                System.out.println("case");         
                BufferedReader br;         
                String str="Token";         
                DatagramSocket ds;         
                DatagramPacket dp;                 

                if(setSendData == true)         {             
                    System.out.println("Enter the Data");             
                    br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));             
                    str = "ClientTwo....." + br.readLine();         }             
                ds = new DatagramSocket(sendport);             
                dp = new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(),str.length(),lclhost,sendport-1000);             
                ds.send(dp);             
                ds.close();             
                System.out.println("Data Sent");             
                setSendData = false;             
                hasToken = false;             
                }         
            void recData()throws Exception     {         
                String msgstr;         
                byte buffer[] = new byte[256];         
                DatagramSocket ds;         
                DatagramPacket dp; 
                ds = new DatagramSocket(recport);        
                //ds = new DatagramSocket(4000);         
                dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);         
                ds.receive(dp);         

                ds.close(); 
                msgstr = new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());         
                System.out.println("The data is "+msgstr);         

                if(msgstr.equals("Token"))             {                 
                    hasToken = true;             
                    }     
                }     

        }
```

Comment: What problem? What error? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is working as expected. Please make sure that you are running all three programs in parallel, meaning open 3 different command prompts and run the following respectively.

java TokenServer

java TokenClient1

java TokenClient2

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting errors saying Exception in thread "main" Java.net.BindException: Address already in use:

Comment: And I don't have old instances of the program running in the background

Comment: Check  who is using the ports, for example(netstat -aon | find "9090"). If the ports used in program are being used by someone, you can change to different ports. It should work.

Comment: Changed my ports to ones that are listening and I'm still getting the error! Very confused

Comment: I'm sure you mist be doing something wrong. Please restart your system and run the programs again.